# Packer user variables from script

Tags: json, devops, packer

I have a number of variables that can be populated from bash queries on execution. I'm struggling to find a way to make this a reality.

Essentially, I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "ssh_name": "root",
    "ssh_pass": "password123",
    "server_version": "grep product.version= ../product.properties | sed 's:product.version=::'"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
```

I've tried several iterations of this, but I can't seem to find a working substitution call.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Is that an example output? What is your input in that case?

Comment: The variable "server_version" should be set from the command that follows. It doesn't, I've tried a couple different ways to approach it, but no luck so far.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it in with a subshell:

```
packer build -var server_version=$(grep product.version= ../product.properties | \
sed 's:product.version=::') template.json
```

Comment: Yea, I get this can be done as passed options, trying to streamline this.

Comment: This is the only way.